# Overfitting my model over my training data of a single sample

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, theano, keras

I am trying to over-fit my model over my training data that consists of only a single sample. The training accuracy comes out to be 1.00. But, when I predict the output for my test data which consists of the same single training input sample, the results are not accurate. The model has been trained for 100 epochs and the loss ~ 1e-4. 
What could be the possible sources of error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: There is clearly something wrong with your code. If acc is 1.0 on sample x, and you predict sample x, of course the correct class will be presented. But yeah, follow Prune's recommendation.

Comment: You should not call it "test data" if it is in your training set. Test set and training set have to be disjunct. Just call it "training data".

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments of your post, it isn't possible to give specific advice without you first providing more details.

Generally speaking, your approach to overfitting a tiny batch (in your case one image) is in essence providing three sanity checks, i.e. that:

1. backprop is functioning
2. the weight updates are doing their job
3. the learning rate is in the correct order of magnitude

As is pointed out by Andrej Karpathy in Lecture 5 of CS231n course at Stanford - ["if you can't overfit on a tiny batch size, things are definitely broken"](https://youtu.be/gYpoJMlgyXA?t=1h1m22s).

This means, given your description, that your implementation is incorrect. I would start by checking each of those three points listed above. For example, alter your test somehow by picking several different images or a btach-size of 5 images instead of one. You could also revise your `predict function`, as that is where there is definitely some discrepancy, given you are getting zero error during training (and so validation?).